# Firebase dynamic link not opening iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Have to mention this dynamic link was working before and suddenly for some reason stop working.

This is the dynamic link: 
`autobavaria1491911550production.page.link`

and This is the link added to Associated Domains in capabilities: `applinks:autobavaria1491911550production.page.link`

and after testing with `apple-app-site-association` the result is:

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "K9B6CPM5NB.com.whipmobility.ios.operation",
        "paths": [
          "NOT /_/*",
          "/*"
        ]
      },
      {
        "appID": "S5Q34K6U59.com.autobavaria.ios.customer",
        "paths": [
          "NOT /_/*",
          "/*"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

`com.autobavaria.ios.customer` is the package name I want the dynamic link to open, which is available in app association but its not happening, and yes App Store ID and team ID is added in firebase console, any idea why is this happening?

Comment: Delete your app and restart your device...check after that.

Comment: Check out this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KLBjAg6HvG0 from 8:00 min for debugging help.

Comment: Thanks @MohitKumar. This is so Weird, after uninstalling the app and restart the phone and install it back, start working again. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: as per firebase, sometimes error comes while downloading apple-app-site-association file associated with your domain. That's why it happens. Please accept my answer if it works. Thanks.

Comment: In my case we have 2 different project in firebase for sandbox and production and the apps under it are having same package name. In my case I guess the problem happens when the sandbox app with same package name from TestFlight overwritten with the app installed from the AppStore (production version). and OS confused in that.

Comment: @Nik we're having a similar problem - but with one Firebase Project containing our `sandbox` app and `production` app (different bundle ids). Oddly, even though the dynamic links were working properly before, and nothing has changed since, now the `sandbox`/`staging` firebase dynamic links are trying to open the appstore (even though the sandbox app is not live on the appstore) and not recognising that the `sandbox` app is installed...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Steps:

1. Delete your app
2. Restart your device.
3. Reinstall your app and test.

As per firebase, sometimes error comes while downloading "apple-app-site-association" file associated with your domain. That's why it happens.

Check out this video: https://youtu.be/KLBjAg6HvG0?t=483 for debugging help.

Setup Dynaminc link from start: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KLBjAg6HvG0

**If you have completed the above-mentioned steps, please check if you have the right methods implemented in your AppDelegate file.**

Method 1:

```
    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        if DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().shouldHandleDynamicLink(fromCustomSchemeURL: url) {
            let dynamicLink = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().dynamicLink(fromCustomSchemeURL: url)
            self.handleDynamicLink(dynamicLink)
            return true
        }
        
        return true
    }
```

Method 2:

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
        if let incomingURL = userActivity.webpageURL {
            print(incomingURL)
            
            let linkHandled = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(incomingURL) { (dynamicLink, error) in
                guard error == nil else {
                    print("Found an error! \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                }
                
                if let dynamicLink = dynamicLink {
                    self.handleDynamicLink(dynamicLink)
                }
            }
            
            if linkHandled {
                return true
            } else {
                //May be do other things with our incoming URL?
                return false
            }
        }
        
        return false
    }
```

Handle Dynamic Link common Method:

```
    func handleDynamicLink(_ dynamicLink: DynamicLink?) {
        guard let dynamicLink = dynamicLink else { return }
        guard let deepLink = dynamicLink.url else { return }
        
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a source / reference (to the docs) that explains why/how this happens? All of a sudden my `staging`/`dev` builds have had their Firebase Dynamic links break (with no changes) but my AppStore live version on `prod` is still working properly. Tearing my hair our over this all week...

Comment: check out the video at via Firebase team: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KLBjAg6HvG0
In this video, you will see couple of scenarios where this happens in iOS.