# iOS Application: Firebase Dynamic Links are not working with latest Pod file

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

We integrated the latest Dynamic link Pod to our iOS application.

Whenever we open the link of firebase no function in triggered in our Appdelegate.
Check the method we implemented in App delegate

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,     restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
 DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(userActivity.webpageURL!) { (dynamiclink, error) in
     if(dynamiclink != nil){
         let aStr = dynamiclink!.url!.absoluteString
         print("reopen url :\(String(describing: aStr.removingPercentEncoding))")
         let decodeUrl = aStr.removingPercentEncoding!
     }
 }
 return true 
}

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
 print("got link1")
 print(" first time url :\(url)")
 let aStr = url.absoluteString
 print("url :\(String(describing: aStr.removingPercentEncoding))")
 let decodeUrl = aStr.removingPercentEncoding!
 if let dynamicLink = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().dynamicLink(fromCustomSchemeURL: url) {
     if dynamicLink.url != nil{
         let aStr = dynamicLink.url!.absoluteString
         let decodUrl = aStr.removingPercentEncoding!
     }
 }
return true }
```

We are using a custom domain in our application, we added them in info.plist too

```
<key>FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains</key>
<array>
    <string>https://page.google.com/newrequest</string>
</array>
<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
<string>YES</string>
```

We added a dynamic link URL to our AssociatedDomains with a prefix of app links like `applinks:page.google.com`

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59765601/2781088 This might help you.

Comment: is it resolved?

Comment: Hello @MohitKumar, thanks for the reply. I tried the link, every thing is fine but its not getting dynamic link details. I need to know , where we can red the long url . currently its not calling any method in Appdelegate. Thank you

Comment: Please don't forget to Vote up if https://stackoverflow.com/a/59765601/2781088 this solved your initial problem. And I have posted the answer below for your problem mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: Hi
I am also facing issue, earlier it was working but suddenly dynamiclink!.url is <null>. can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In iOS 13, AppDelegate methods will not call. Add SceneDelegate to your project.  Add 
`func scene(_ scene: UIScene, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity) { 
 print(userActivity.webpageURL)
}`

we will get userActivity.webpageURL will be our long dynamic link.

Comment: follow this link : https://medium.com/@fenceguest/deeplink-handler-in-swift-5-ios-13-eec88c2c5fe7. your day will save thank you

Comment: hi I am facing the same error please check the link below help me if you have a solution stackoverflow.com/q/67019905/11468227

Answer (score 7):

### Answer for Swift 5.0 and iOS 14.0

For those who are still struggling on managing deep links in SceneDelegate, this answer might helpful.

**Case 1: App is running (foreground & background):**

First you should keep in mind that after iOS 13 update the deep links are not managed by the `UIApplicationDelegate`, this job is hand over to `SceneDelegate`.

So for the first case you need to add below method to handle the event when user clicks on deep link

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity) {
        
        guard userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb,
            let url = userActivity.webpageURL,
            let host = url.host else {
                return
        }
        
        DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(url) { dynamicLink, error in
            guard error == nil,
                let dynamicLink = dynamicLink,
                let urlString = dynamicLink.url?.absoluteString else {
                    return
            }
            print("Dynamic link host: \(host)")
            print("Dyanmic link url: \(urlString)")
            
            // Handle deep links
            self.handleDeepLink(urlString: urlString)
            
            print("Dynamic link match type: \(dynamicLink.matchType.rawValue)")
        }
    }
```

**Case 2: App is not running (Kill mode):**

If the application is not running the the deep links are available in `connectionOptions` of the `SceneDelegate`. So you need to write a code to manage Firebase deep links in `willConnectTo(:)` method.

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

        if let userActivity = connectionOptions.userActivities.first {
            if let incomingURL = userActivity.webpageURL {
                _ = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(incomingURL) { (dynamicLink, error) in
                    guard error == nil else { return }
                    if let dynamicLink = dynamicLink {
                        if let urlString = dynamicLink.url?.absoluteString {
                            // Handle deep links
                            self.handleDeepLink(urlString: urlString)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wow. I've been wondering for so long now why it wasn't working. I knew I had followed their docs exactly. Thank you!

Comment: hi I am facing the same error please check the link below help me if you have a solution stackoverflow.com/q/67019905/11468227

Comment: The best solution I have ever found on the internet.
Thanks a lot, you saved my whole day buddy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59765601/2781088 This might solve your initial problem for DL and follow the below code for the problem mentioned in the comments.

You can get the URL in the following functions (Add these methods into your App Delegate):

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    if DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().shouldHandleDynamicLink(fromCustomSchemeURL: url) {
            let dynamicLink = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().dynamicLink(fromCustomSchemeURL: url)
            self.handleDynamicLink(dynamicLink)
            return true
    }
}
```

And

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
        if let incomingURL = userActivity.webpageURL {
            print(incomingURL)

            let linkHandled = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(incomingURL) { (dynamicLink, error) in
                guard error == nil else {
                    print("Found an error! \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                }

                if let dynamicLink = dynamicLink {
                    self.handleDynamicLink(dynamicLink)
                }
            }

            if linkHandled {
                return true
            }
            else {
                //May be do other things with our incoming URL?
                return false
            }
        }

        return false
    }
```

handleDynamicLink method:

```
func handleDynamicLink(_ dynamicLink: DynamicLink?) {
        guard let dynamicLink = dynamicLink else { return }
        guard let deepLink = dynamicLink.url else { return }
    }
```

Don't forget to add this: [image]

Hope that will solve your issue.

Comment: its not triggered any method.  check this out once https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/895

Comment: you can check this video for issue identification as well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KLBjAg6HvG0

Comment: added associated Domains also perfect, its opening correctly to my app from notes application with dynamic link prefix. but if I open the direct dynamic link got error in the console as "6.17.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023000] Deep Link Web URL query is empty"

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56483454/2781088 if this solves your problem

Comment: hi I am facing the same error please check the link below help me if you have a solution stackoverflow.com/q/67019905/11468227