# Dynamic link web URL query item is empty in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links, ios-universal-links

I am getting deeplink URL from QRCODE scan but it is showing Web URL query is empty (implemented with firebase dynamic links). Associated domains set to "applinks:avrhub.page.link/Product".

"FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains" in info.plist set to "https://avrhub.page.link" and "https://avrhub.page.link/Product"

[image]

**Deeplink url:[image]**

**Code For Deeplinking:**

```
func handleIncomingDynamicLink(_ dynamicLink:DynamicLink){
    
    
    
    guard let url = dynamicLink.url else {
            print("My Dynamic Link object has no url")
            return
        }
        print("Your Incoming link Parameter is \(url.absoluteString)")
        
        guard let components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false),
        let queryItems = components.queryItems else {return}
        for queryItem in queryItems {
            
            Api.Params.inputProductId = Int(queryItem.value!)!
            print("Parameter \(queryItem.name) has a value of \(queryItem.value ?? "")")
        }
        
        Switcher.updateRootVC()
        Api.Params.isDeepLink = true

        if dynamicLink.matchType == .unique {
            print("The dynamic link is Unique")
        }
    }


func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
             
    if let incomingURL = userActivity.webpageURL {
        print("incoming URL is \(incomingURL)")
        let linkHandled = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(incomingURL) { ( dynamicLink, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                print("Found an error \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            if let dynamicLink = dynamicLink {
                self.handleIncomingDynamicLink(dynamicLink)
            }
            
        }
        if linkHandled {
  
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
    
    return false
    
}


          
    func application(
        _ app: UIApplication,
        open url: URL,
        options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]
    ) -> Bool {

        ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
            app,
            open: url,
            sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
            annotation: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]
        )
        
        
        
        if let dynamicLink = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().dynamicLink(fromCustomSchemeURL: url){
            self.handleIncomingDynamicLink(dynamicLink)
            return true
        } else {
            return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url)
        }


    }
```

Even analytics is not giving any error

[image]

Comment: Given it seems the app is opening when you tap on the universal link, seems that that piece is set up.  Guessing it is something in terms of how the full universal link was composed.  Was the link created in firebase console?  Programatically?

Comment: are you able to see your link by debugging it in the browser? `example.page.link/suffix?d=1`

Comment: @SteveB , the is created by backend developer and embedded in QRCode , So when i scan , the app opens .. but the problem is , I want to get that product id to display the product in my app , but im getting nil

Comment: Is the product ID the "30" in your example?

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan when i pass incomingURL in linkHandled .. the result im getting is null ... but when i pass exactly the same URL(which i registered in firebase console) without productID which is "https://avrhub.page.link/Product" Im getting dynamic link value ... but i want that with dynamic product id ... how can i register that dynamic product id in Firebase Dynamic Link Console

Comment: @SteveB yes, the product id is 30 , and it will be dynamic in every QRCode .... how can i register that dynamic id in Firebase dynamic link console ?

Comment: @HanzalaRaza product id is dynamic so you need to create dynamic link on the go. Create it programmatically by using Firebase's dynamic link SDK.

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan , so you mean that , after QRCode scan when app opens , i need to create dynamic link from available URL ? Or You want me to create QRCode with Embedded URL by my own ?

Comment: No - seems your BE dev didn't properly generate the dynamic link

Comment: @SteveB , He is not generating dynamiclink , He just create URL and embed in QRCode , Its my task to register that URL on Dynamic Link console and get the value of product id

Comment: Which URL is he creating?  Just the 'incomingURL' in your example?  In which case, you aren't fully utliizing the Firebase Dynamic link concept and you should stop calling 'handleIncomingDynamicLink' and instead just parse the incomingURL and grab the product ID.  Seems overkill for you to take his link, go through the pain of creating a dynamic link just to get to the ID that you already have.

Comment: @SteveB , Exactly .... Now i am just getting the ID from URL and applying my logic ... and dynamic link is just for opening application from URL

Comment: If you get your desired answer please mark it as correct ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you cannot create a dynamic link with variable product id in the firebase console, instead you need to generate it on the go. You can also include additional parameters if needed which may help in analytics for example if you would like to know which user share the link and what its impact...

In my opinion it's better to add product id as query parameter in the link. Moreover it will also be helpful in case of multi parameters. You can parse it easily with the parameter name for example:

```
var productId: String?
let urlComponents = URLComponents(string: urlString)
if let queryItems = urlComponents?.queryItems {
    for queryItem in queryItems {
        if queryItem.name == "product_id" {
           productId = queryItem.value
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my code for generating dynamic link programmatically.

```
func generateAndShareDynamicLink(event: Event, controller: UIViewController, presentationCompletion: @escaping (() -> Void), dismissCompletion: @escaping (() -> Void) ) {
        
        let user = Utility.shared.getCurrentUser()!
        let ownReferralCode = user.ownReferralCode.value
        let offerShareUrlString = youAPILink + "?referral=" + ownReferralCode + "&event_id=" + event.id.value + "&shared_by=" + user.userId.value + "&shared_by_name=" + user.fullName.value
        
        let url = URL(string: offerShareUrlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!)!
        
        let iOSNavigationParams = DynamicLinkNavigationInfoParameters()
        iOSNavigationParams.isForcedRedirectEnabled = false
        
        let linkComponents = DynamicLinkComponents(link: url, domainURIPrefix: dynamicLinkGenaricDomain)!
        linkComponents.navigationInfoParameters = iOSNavigationParams
        linkComponents.iOSParameters = DynamicLinkIOSParameters(bundleID: bundleId)
        linkComponents.iOSParameters?.appStoreID = kAppStoreId
        linkComponents.iOSParameters?.customScheme = theBarCodeInviteScheme
        
        linkComponents.androidParameters = DynamicLinkAndroidParameters(packageName: androidPackageName)
        
        let descText = "\(user.fullName.value) has shared an event with you, check it out!"
        linkComponents.socialMetaTagParameters = DynamicLinkSocialMetaTagParameters()
        linkComponents.socialMetaTagParameters?.title = "App Name"
        linkComponents.socialMetaTagParameters?.descriptionText = descText
        linkComponents.socialMetaTagParameters?.imageURL = tbcLogoUrl
        
        linkComponents.otherPlatformParameters = DynamicLinkOtherPlatformParameters()
        linkComponents.otherPlatformParameters?.fallbackUrl = URL(string: barCodeDomainURLString)
        
        linkComponents.shorten { (shortUrl, warnings, error) in
            
            guard error == nil else {
                presentationCompletion()
                controller.showAlertController(title: "Share Event", msg: error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            
            if let warnings = warnings {
                debugPrint("Dynamic link generation warnings: \(String(describing: warnings))")
            }
            
            let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [descText, shortUrl!], applicationActivities: nil)
            activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = controller.view
            activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = { (activityType, completed:Bool, returnedItems:[Any]?, error: Error?) in
                dismissCompletion()
            }
            controller.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: {
                presentationCompletion()
            })
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: this same thing is available on the multiple platforms, you can also generate it on your back end as well.

Comment: hi I am facing the same error please check the link below help me if you have a solution stackoverflow.com/q/67019905/11468227

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue in that I always gets `nil` value while trying to get the Firebase Dynamic link from below function

`DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().dynamicLink(:)`

I found on useful post on Github that explains that we need to add the domain in `.plist` file which is used in the dynamic link.

This works for me, may be this will help someone.

You can add your domain in plist like below:

```
<key>FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains</key>
    <array>
        <string><YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME></string>
    </array>
```

Make sure that you are specifying https:// or http:// in the domain name.

**Note:** if you wish to explore how to handle Firebase dynamic links for iOS 13 and higher version iOS.
[You can visit this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60274501/ios-application-firebase-dynamic-links-are-not-working-with-latest-pod-file/66667487#66667487)

Comment: hi I am facing the same error please check the link below help me if you have a solution stackoverflow.com/q/67019905/11468227

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other answer that the best way to solve this is to get the back end developer to use the Firebase Dynamic Links SDK to properly generate a dynamic link and embed in the QR code.

However, if you don't have control of that, then you can take the incoming link and parse it for the product ID that is embedded.  In which case, you don't need to use some of the Dynamic link capabilities for example, you could instead do the below:

```
if let incomingURL = userActivity.webpageURL {
    print("incoming URL is \(incomingURL)")
    handleIncomingURL(incomingURL)
}
```

//quick and dirty parse - you could do something a bit more robust based on your circumstances

```
func handleIncomingURL(_ url:URL) {
    
    guard let components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true), let host = components.host else {
        return
    }
    var pathComponents = components.path.components(separatedBy: "/")
    // the first component is empty
    pathComponents.removeFirst()
    
    if pathComponents[0] == "Product" && pathComponents[1] != nil {
        print("found productId: \(pathComponents[1])")
        //Action here: jump to the right page from here, now that you have a product ID to work with
    } else {
        print("invalid URL path for my use case....")
    }
}
```