# Handling dynamic link from Firebase in swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have made a dynamic link in Firebase, which op my iOS app, when I click it.
The problem is, that I can't print information about the link.

I use this function in the AppDelegate file to handle the dynamic link:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
        print("Handeling dynamic link")
        if let incomingURL = userActivity.webpageURL {
            print("Incoming URL is \(incomingURL)")
            let linkHandled = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(incomingURL) { (dynamicLink, error) in
                guard error == nil else {
                    print("Found an error! \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                }
                if let dynamicLink = dynamicLink {
                    self.handleIncomingDynamicLink(dynamicLink)
                }
            }
            if linkHandled {
                return true
            } else {
                // Maybe do other things with our incoming url
                return false
            }
        }
        return false
    }
```

When I click on a dynamic link and open the app, none of the print statements is printed to the console.

It seems like this function is never tapped into.

The handleDynamicLink function is:

```
func handleIncomingDynamicLink(_ dynamicLink: DynamicLink) {
        guard let url = dynamicLink.url else {
            print("That is weird. My dynamic link object has no url")
            return
        }
        print("Your incoming link parameter is \(url.absoluteString)")
}
```

I want to print information about the url so I can debug and use the information in the url to redirect to pages in the app.

When I'm testing this, I run the app on an iPhone connected to my mac.
I don't run it on the iOS simulator.

Answer (score 1):

The code in your UIApplication delegate method looks good. The only difference I see with the way you have yours compared to mine is I'm returning true in the last line & you're returning false.

By the way, put breakpoints in that UIApplication delegate method & let me know if you're ever even getting to the first line in that delegate method. Are you able to hit any breakpoints in your `handleIncomingDynamicLink()` method?

**Also, try adding this in `applicationDidBecomeActive`:**

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    guard let url = self.launchURL else { return }
    self.launchURL = nil
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0, execute: {     // wait to init. notifs.
        DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(url) { (dynamiclink, error) in
            if let dynamiclink = dynamiclink {
                self.handleIncomingDynamicLink(dynamiclink)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

**And add this:**

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication,
                      open url: URL,
                      options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {                      
    print("RECEIVED A URL THROUGH A CUSTOM SCHEME: \(url.absoluteString)")
    if let dynamicLink = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().dynamicLink(fromCustomSchemeURL: url) {
        self.handleIncomingDynamicLink(dynamicLink)
        return true
    } else { // Maybe handle Google or Facebook sign-in here
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried putting break points in the UIApplication delegate. I am not able to get to the first line in delegate method I posted. 

I am only able to enter this function:

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
}

I have tried pasting your function applicationDidBecomeActive. I get the error: appDelegate has no member launcURL

Comment: When are you creating this launchURL?

Comment: I think I found the answer, dynamic links is not handle in the AppDelegate anymore, but are moved to SceneDelegate in swift 5.0: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66667487/7841636

Answer (score 0):

No need to hassle. No need to use AppDelegate or SceneDelegate.
Just use this code

```
@main
struct MyApplication: App {
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      ContentView()
        .onOpenURL { url in
          // handle the URL that must be opened
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Enjoy :)